# Power BI and parquet at ADLS Gen2

Tags: powerbi, parquet, powerbi-desktop

I'm able to connect to ADLS Gen2 from Power BI Desktop and work on CSV files.

The issue is that the same doesn't work for Parquet format. *Have you ever worked with parquet at Power BI Desktop?*

The problem arise when after adding parquet table, I click on Binary reference - Power Query is unable to read/preview parquet data. I tried both with and w/o snappy compression.

Also I tried to write query manually:

```
let
    Source = AzureStorage.DataLake("https://xxx.dfs.core.windows.net/yyy/data.parquet"),
    #"File" = Source{[#"Folder Path"="https://xxx.dfs.core.windows.net/yyy/data.parquet",Name="data.parquet"]}[Content],
    #"Imported File" = Parquet.Document(#"File")
in
    #"Imported File"
```

But got the following exception:

> The name 'Parquet.Document' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled
>   correctly.

Despite the fact that `Parquet.Document` function [is documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powerquery-m/parquet-document). I'm using Poewr BI Desktop latest version (Dec 2019).

P.S. I've also faced the same issue while developing DAX model for AAS from Visual Studio SSDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you can't work directly with parquet files in Power BI Desktop. You'll need to leverage something like [Azure Data Factory's wrangling data flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/wrangling-data-flow-overview) to convert to CSV or another consumable format first.

It looks like the function you're referring to was specifically added for [this new feature in Azure Data Factory](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory/parquet-format-support-added-to-wrangling-data-flow-in-azure/bc-p/1158594), which allows usage of Parquet files in wrangling data flows.

This might come soon for the Power BI Service's dataflows, too, but that's speculation on my part.

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to successfully read parquet files stored in ADLSG2 via a Power BI Dataflow.

Unfortunately you cannot progress to completion via the gui; Parquet format is not natively detected as a source datatype at the time of this writing. To get around the issue, just use the advanced query editor (in order to progress to the advanced editor, just select the JSON or alternative datatype, then overwrite the M code in the Advanced query editor).

Note: This does not currently work with the June 2020 release of PowerBI Desktop. It only works via a dataflow from what I can tell:

```
let
  Source = AzureStorage.DataLake("https://xxxxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/Container"),
  Navigation = Parquet.Document(Source{[#"Folder Path" = "https://xxxxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/yourcontainer/yoursubfolder/", Name = "yourParquetFile"]}[Content]),
  #"Remove columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Navigation, Table.ColumnsOfType(Navigation, {type table, type record, type list, type nullable binary, type binary, type function}))
in
  #"Remove columns"
```

Comment: Got this to work as well. Are there any options for the Parquet.Document()? The documentation is extremely lacking. Being able to only read specific columns would make sense (it is a columnar storage format). Also, row-level filtering is supported if I use pyarrow or spark too. I am just not sure if Parquet.Document supports these features

Answer (score 2):

Power BI supports this natively now.

[image]

Just paste in the url to the parquet file on your lake/storage account and you're good to go.  Apparently this isn't slated to go live until [March 2021](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2020wave2/cdm-data-integration/parquet-connector), but it appears for me in the Dec 2020 release.

Comment: This also works for local files in PowerBI Desktop if you paste the Windows file path as the URL. e.g. `C:\path\to\file.parquet`.